# StringFormat not working on TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, currency, mask, string-formatting

I'm trying to make a currency formatted textbox but it's not working.

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="_valueTxt" Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat={}{0:C}}"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
...
string _amount;
public string Amount
{
    get { return _amount; }
    set { _amount = value; }
}
...
public MyWindow()
{
    Amount = "1235533";
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Value I expect to see in my textbox:

$1.235.533,00

But it's showing:

1235533

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use `StringFormat` with numerical format strings if you're binding to a number.  Your `Amount` property is already a `string`, so you will get it as-is.

If you change the `Amount` property to be a numerical value, you will get what you expect, ie:

```
double _amount;
public double Amount
{
    get { return _amount; }
    set { _amount = value; }
}
...
public MyWindow()
{
    Amount = 1235533;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Note that you may also want to make `Amount` either a `DependencyProperty` or have it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  This will allow changes to the value to be reflected in the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
internal class MyClass
{
    private double amount = 1209382;

    public string Amount
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0:C}", amount); }
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        MyClass instance = new MyClass();
        Console.WriteLine(instance.Amount);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```